# How can I extract the metadata and bitrate info from a audio/video file in python

Tags: python, avconv, pydub

What I would like to do is get the metadata from audio or video files and save it to a database record, so far the only way to do this seems to save AVCONV to a file using a subprocess.Open call then read that file, is there any libraries that can do this to save some steps? I couldn't find a way to do it with Pydub or PySox. Here is my simplistic hamfisted beginner code I used that does work and puts the bitrate, duration, etc info into a variable audio_info and the metadata into metadata. OGG output worked differently than the other formats i tested (which was a ton of video and audio!).

```
    try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(["avconv" , "-i" , music_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            out, err = p.communicate()
            retcode = p.wait()
    except IOError,e:
            pass
    extension = uploaded_music_file[-3:]
    if "ogg" not in [err , extension]:
            if "Metadata:" in err:
                    list = err.split("Metadata:")
                    holder = list[1].split("Duration:")
                    metadata = holder[0]
                    audio_info = holder[1].replace("At least one output file must be specified","")
                    print metadata
                    print audio_info
            else:
                    list = err.split("Duration:")
                    audio_info = list[1].replace("At least one output file must be specified","")
                    print "No Metadata"
                    print audio_info
    else:
            list = err.split("Duration:")
            if "Metadata:" in list[1]:
                    data = list[1].split("Metadata:")
                    metadata = data[1].replace("At least one output file must be specified","")
                    audio_info = data[0]
                    print metadata
                    print audio_info
            else:
                    audio_info = list[1].replace("At least one output file must be specified","")
                    print "No Metadata"
                    print audio_info
if (audio_info):
            print "AUDIO INFO:"
            cursor.execute("UPDATE songDB SET audio_info = %s WHERE id = %s" ,[ audio_info , song_id ] )
            if (metadata):
                    print "METADATA:"
                    cursor.execute("songDB pack_song SET metadata = %s WHERE id = %s" ,[ metadata , song_id ] )
```

Comment: @Oz123 just added the code i cobbled together that does actually work! - but the output is pretty janky

Answer (score 6):

Pydub *does* include a function for retrieving metadata, `pydub.utils.mediainfo("/path/to/file")`, though pydub is only designed to deal with audio files. However the current implementation of `mediainfo` doesn't seem to be doing anything audio specific, so it may work for you.

It returns a dictionary of metadata as provided by ffmpeg/libav (specifically the ffprobe / avprobe utility)

```
>>> from pydub.utils import mediainfo
>>> mediainfo("/path/to/file.mp3")
```

which, for the test1.mp3 file used by pydub's unit tests, returns:

```
{
  u'DISPOSITION': {
    u'attached_pic': u'0',
    u'clean_effects': u'0',
    u'comment': u'0',
    u'default': u'0',
    u'dub': u'0',
    u'forced': u'0',
    u'hearing_impaired': u'0',
    u'karaoke': u'0',
    u'lyrics': u'0',
    u'original': u'0',
    u'visual_impaired': u'0'
  },
  u'TAG': {u'encoder': u'Lavf55.12.100'},
  u'avg_frame_rate': u'0/0',
  u'bit_rate': u'96179',
  u'bits_per_sample': u'0',
  u'channel_layout': u'stereo',
  u'channels': u'2',
  u'codec_long_name': u'MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)',
  u'codec_name': u'mp3',
  u'codec_tag': u'0x0000',
  u'codec_tag_string': u'[0][0][0][0]',
  u'codec_time_base': u'1/32000',
  u'codec_type': u'audio',
  u'duration': u'10.044000',
  u'duration_ts': u'141740928',
  u'filename': u'/Users/jiaaro/Documents/code/pydub/test/data/test1.mp3',
  u'format_long_name': u'MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)',
  u'format_name': u'mp3',
  u'id': u'N/A',
  u'index': u'0',
  u'max_bit_rate': u'N/A',
  u'nb_frames': u'N/A',
  u'nb_programs': u'0',
  u'nb_read_frames': u'N/A',
  u'nb_read_packets': u'N/A',
  u'nb_streams': u'1',
  u'probe_score': u'51',
  u'profile': u'unknown',
  u'r_frame_rate': u'0/0',
  u'sample_fmt': u's16p',
  u'sample_rate': u'32000',
  u'size': u'120753',
  u'start_pts': u'487305',
  u'start_time': u'0.034531',
  u'time_base': u'1/14112000'
}
```

Comment: Pydub is excellent! Oneliner to convert an alac file including tags and cover two mp3: `AudioSegment.from_file(src).export(dst, format='mp3', tags=mediainfo(src)['TAG'])`